# Rendering single mesh color change

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a grid that contains boxes, very similar to http://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_interactive_voxelpainter.  Now I initiated a hover state when a box on the scene is `mouseover` it turns the background gray.  Which is great!  Except when I multiple `"box"` on the grid and I go to change the `material` background color of the `hovered` item, it renders all of the `"box's"` with a gray background.

Heres what I am doing:

```
var voxel = new THREE.Mesh( this.cubeGeometry, this.cubeMaterial );
voxel.position.copy( intersect.point ).add( intersect.face.normal );
voxel.position.divideScalar( 50 ).floor().multiplyScalar( 50 ).addScalar( 25 );
this.scene.add( voxel );
this.blocks.push( voxel );
var domEvents   = new THREEx.DomEvents(this.camera, this.renderer.domElement)
// DOM events for inside 3d rendering
domEvents.addEventListener(voxel, 'mouseover', this.onDocumentMouseOverCube.bind(this),false);
domEvents.addEventListener(voxel, 'mouseout', this.onDocumentMouseOutCube.bind(this),false);
```

Here we create our `box` - we than give it `eventListeners` for that specific `mesh`.  Once this `mesh` is hovered over, our `mouseover` is executed:

```
this.mouse.x = ( event.origDomEvent.clientX / this.renderer.domElement.width ) * 2 - 1;
this.mouse.y = - ( event.origDomEvent.clientY / this.renderer.domElement.height ) * 2 + 1;

this.raycaster.setFromCamera( this.mouse, this.camera );
var intersects = this.raycaster.intersectObjects( this.blocks );
if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

    var intersect = intersects[ 0 ];

    if ( intersect.object != this.plane ) {
        console.log(intersect.object);


        // update color on hover
        intersect.object.material.color.setHex(this.colorHover);
        console.log("hover color");
        this.render();
    }
}
```

Now this works great, the only issue is - `this.render()` is called `(this.renderer.render( this.scene, this.camera ))` like it should be.  But when I have multiple `box's` on it goes ahead and changes every single `background` color of each `box`  I have even `logged` all my objects to confirm `object.material.color` is the gray hex for only one `box` and that not all of the `box's` are being set, which proves to be true.  I am sending the correct data over.  So I am assuming it has to do with the `rendering` of the actual engine?

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only one instance of the material, which is shared among the meshes. The easy solution is to clone the material for each mesh:

`var voxel = new THREE.Mesh( this.cubeGeometry, this.cubeMaterial.clone() );`

Now every box accepts its own color.

---

I dont know if this still applies but thinking about performance you would want to go with a custom **shader material**, because the attributes and vertex/fragment programs are copied by reference then. See this post [Three.js, sharing ShaderMaterial between meshes but with different uniform sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15597846/three-js-sharing-shadermaterial-between-meshes-but-with-different-uniform-sets).

Example code:

```
var phongShader = THREE.ShaderLib.phong;
this.shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: phongShader.uniforms,
    vertexShader: phongShader.vertexShader,
    fragmentShader: phongShader.fragmentShader,
    lights:true
});
var voxel = new THREE.Mesh( this.cubeGeometry, this.shaderMaterial.clone() );
```

And then you change the color via uniforms like so:

```
intersect.object.material.uniforms.diffuse.value.setHex( this.colorHover );
```

Three.js r.71

PS: cloning the default Phong material in r.71 also shows only one programm in the renderer info for me, so maybe Three.js is optimizing this internally.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply @FalkThiele but I am utilizing shaders, those are disabled.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand what you want to say with your comment, did you try the material cloning approach?

Comment: No I will try shortly here.

Comment: Hey Thanks so much that worked perfectly!  Real quick, why did I have to use clone?  Is it because `this.material` is a global property that `three` uses when rendering?  So when I changed `color` of the material, it actually effected the entire property?

Comment: Yes, assigning it to a mesh does not create a new instance of the material.

Comment: Falk you would assign calling intersect.object.material would be calling the instance of that object.