# Three.js - About storage of geometries and materials

Tags: caching, memory, three.js, geometry

We can create multiple meshes with the same geometry and material. But are there duplicates in the properties of each meshes ?
I'm concerned about memory problems. Thanks !

Comment: What properties are you talking about ? Have a `console.log(mesh)` to see. : you may want to keep the geometry and material parameters... the rest are few numbers and booleans used to define the orientation, position, shadow casting...

Comment: I'm talking about those two properties exactly, there are apparently not reference to an uuid but a instance. I mean, the same geometry with the same uuid is duplicate throught the meshes.  it's right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in `THREE.Mesh` code :

```
THREE.Mesh = function ( geometry, material ) {

    THREE.Object3D.call( this );

    this.type = 'Mesh';

    this.geometry = geometry !== undefined ? geometry : new THREE.Geometry();
    this.material = material !== undefined ? material : new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: Math.random() * 0xffffff } );

    this.updateMorphTargets();

};
```

And in the `clone` method :

```
THREE.Mesh.prototype.clone = function () {

    return new this.constructor( this.geometry, this.material ).copy( this );

};
```

That is to say when creating a mesh from a geometry/a material, or cloning a mesh, its geometry and material properties are references to the same objects. If you modify the material's color, or the geometry's vertices, both original and copy will have the new color/geometry.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145275/many-meshes-with-the-same-geometry-and-material-can-i-change-their-colors?rq=1

Comment: Perfect ! That what I wanted to know ! Sources are really helpfull, thanks !

Comment: I haven't enough reputation points yet... but, i'll remember ! Be sure !

Comment: @Tiramitsu you can always validate answers. I upvoted your question to give you some initial reputation

Answer (score 0):

I think the best idea is cloning

```
var Box_geometry = Box_geometry.clone();
var Box_material = Box_material.clone();
```

[I've prepared a simple example in JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Freeman555/otpuprxr/).

r.73

Comment: The clone method create a new and separate geometry for each meshes, that is not my goal. I wanted to know if it exist a way for link all the meshes to the same geometry (reference to the a geometry object). Otherwise, hundred meshes in the scene could spend a lot of memory ! Each object3D has a uuid, it can be usefull, or not ? thanks !

Comment: I don't think so, [please take a look in mrdoob page](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/4796)